# Variable Implicitly Declared and Prototypes

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

trying to keep this short. Using phpstorm to look over my code and got a few errors.

It says my function naming locations has a "Variable Implicitly Declared"

```
function towngate10() {
    updateDisplay(locations[10].description);
    if (!gate10) {
        score = score+5;
        gate10 = true;
    }
    playerLocation = 10;
    displayScore();
    document.getElementById("goNorth").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("goSouth").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("goEast").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("goWest").disabled=true;
}
```

Also, I just want to make sure I went about my prototypes correctly
Just a sample

Global Arrays:

```
var locations = [10];
locations[0] = new Location(0,"Intersection","This is where you awoke.");
locations[1] = new Location(1,"Cornfield","The cornfields expand for miles.");
locations[2] = new Location(2,"Lake","A large lake that is formed by a river flowing from the East.", new Item(1,"Fish","An old rotting fish."));
locations[3] = new Location(3,"Outside Cave","Entrance to the dark cave.");
```

Location function:

```
function Location(id, name, description, item) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.item = item;
    this.toString = function() {
        return "Location: " + this.name + " - " + this.description; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is plain JS, `var locations=[10];` would only declare an array with one element (`10`) in it, not an "empty" array with 10 slots.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `var` to declare variables like `score` and `gate10` and `playerLocation` so they aren't implicit globals.

Comment: What do you think this has to do with prototypes?

Comment: @torazaburo My professor told us that the last two pieces of code were prototypes

Comment: @EmeraldX find a new professor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding variables being implicitly declared:

```
if (!gate10) {
    score = score+5;
    gate10 = true;
}
```

and

```
playerLocation = 10;
```

score,gate and playerLocation are being created as 'global' variables. Phpstorm will alert you to this. Unless they are intended to be globally accessible, declare the variables with var instead. This will make the variables local only to the scope in which it's created:

```
if (!gate10) {
    var score = score+5;
    var gate10 = true;
}
```

and

```
var playerLocation = 10;
```

I suggest you read more about [variable scoping](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Global variables can leave gaps in your security if they aren't properly handled.

Comment: I have global variables:                                                             var score = 0;
 var scoreField ="";
 var playerLocation = 0;
 var inventory = "";'    ----- does this at all help in this case, or should the individual variables help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Declaring var before a variable means it's local only to the scope it was declared in. A global variable means you do not have 'var' before the variable when you create it.